# Pass parameter to select dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to pass the column to be selected in a dataframe as a parameter as I change each time for the moment I have done this. It actually works

```
object PCA extends App{
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
 val strPath="C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/testBis2.txt"
val intial_Data=spark.read.option("header",true).csv(strPath)
val inputData=intial_Data.select("col1","col2").show
}
```

I want to pass a parameter to the select so I did this

```
     object PCA extends App{
            val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
             val strPath="C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/testBis2.txt"
             val columns="col1","col2"
            val intial_Data=spark.read.option("header",true).csv(strPath)
           val listcolu=intial_Data.columns
foreach(string s in listcolu)
{create the list insert the column name 
}
        }
```

It hasn't even accepted what it should do. The aim is to pass it each time as parameter.

Comment: You should [read the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val colsList = List(col("col1"),col("col2"))
intial_Data.select(colsList:_*).show
```

Comment: Hi friends thanks for your help , if you may do a favor please check my update , how can create automatically the list using an array of string that contains name of column with for or foreach , please any help thanks ,am new to scala